# Are there any Big Bounce models where the laws of physics (even the most fundamental ones) would change between cycles?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, laws-of-physics

Big Crunch-Big Bang models (usually called Big Bounce models or cosmological oscillatory models) are highly unlikely to happen due to the discovery of the accelerated expansion of the universe.

But even then, just as a theoretical physics exercise, let's assume a Big Crunch happened and then a Big Bang occured. John Wheeler, one of the first physicists that thought about this kind of oscillatory cosmological model, proposed that the universe would change its laws (even the most fundamental ones) between cycles [1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2602-4_9).

My question is: Is there any other Big Bounce/Oscillatory model of the universe where the laws of physics (even the most fundamental ones) would change between cycles?

Comment: You can make your own up. There's no data to prove or disprove any of this, so it's fair game.

Comment: @rfl as I am not a professional physicist, I doubt I could do that. Although I see the irony in your comment, do you know about any model where fundamental laws could change between cycles?